# Impossible to Run Cron after civicrm-4.7.14-wordpress update

Tags: issues, cron, upgrade, 4.7.14

I just update my civicrm-4.7.14-wordpress, and the Cron don't run anymore.

Here is the displayed message in the log :

> [10-Dec-2016 08:15:01 UTC] PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed
>   opening required '../civicrm.config.php'
>   (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear') in
>   path-to-html-root/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php on
>   line 29

Many thanks for the help !

Regards

MG

Answer (score 1):

When updating civicrm, I've always found the need to update the permissions in root/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php (or cli.php) to be executable.  Hope this solves your problem.